# Creating an inner WebAPI 2.0 loop

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, webapi

I'm writing WebAPI 2.0 using MongoDB as my database.

In the process of writing, there was a need to create an inner loop.

I did this:
in Startup in

```
    ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Task.Run (() => _MainClass.InnerLoop ()); // This function has this inner loop
    }
```

Later, I had to pass the MongoDB database context "DbContext" to this function.

I didn't know how to do it, so I did it like this:

1. I created a "post" to which I moved the content of the previous function. (somehow "DbContext" is passed through the interface. As you know this way, point it in the comment).
2. Inside _MainClass.InnerLoop() I put

```
    public void InnerLoop()
    
    {
        
    while(true)
        {
           
            FunctionToHttpRequest(@"http://localhost:5000/api/MyController RunInnerLoop");
        
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

I got an effect that is an imitation of what I wanted.
A separate thread is that some customers get an error:

> "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The
> remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

But I am working on it, as you can tell in the commentary.

Question from this thread:
How to do such a loop "professionally" ie without calling itself, but passing "DbContext" to this loop?

Comment: Fix fomrating of code.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Bos for formating code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coped with the problem myself, I want to share the solution. If you have any comments, please write.

I have modified

```
public class BaseService
 {     

      protected readonly IDbContext DbContext;

      public static IDbContext public_base_dbContext {get; private set;}

      public BaseService (IDbContext dbContext)
      {
           public_base_dbContext = dbContext;
           DbContext = dbContext;
      }

 }
```

and wrote to

```
public void InnerLoop ()
{
IDbContext _dbContext;
do
{
      _dbContext = BaseService.public_base_dbContext;

      if (_dbContext == null)
      {
           Thread.Sleep (1000);
            Console.WriteLine (DateTime.Now + "IDbContext search starting ...");
      }
} while (_dbContext == null);
```

And this way it hooks DbContext from MongoDB and I don't need to call API inside.